# Accessing ArcGIS Pro using ArcGIS Online public account?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, arcgis-license-manager

When l try to log into ArcGIS Pro it does not accept because my ArcGIS Online account is a public account.

How can l fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that the message you are seeing is:

> Your account could not be used to authorize ArcGIS Pro because it is
>   an ArcGIS Public Account.

[image]

> If you don't have an ArcGIS organization account, you can sign up for an ArcGIS free trial  that includes an **ArcGIS Online organization** and access to ArcGIS Pro, ArcGIS Pro extension products, and other apps.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/sign-in-troubleshooting.htm

**ESRI support** is https://support.esri.com/en/contact-tech-support

Comment: about 4 years ago l sign up, but didn't use. now l want to sign up by another mail but it doesn't accept phone number.

Comment: You best option is to contact esri support as they can access your account details and transfer or migrate your information. No GIS-SE member can help you on that side of your issue. There maybe a cost/subscription involved.